# MDI form doesn't show even though it should

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I want to open an Mdi childform inside a parentform when i open a text file. The thing is, it doesn't show at all. Before you ask, yes the main form it is absolutely set as an MDI container. Please ignore the fact that the childform doesn't do anything except the supposed showing.

```
 private void OpenToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Statement files|* .STA" };
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StatementForm statementForm = new StatementForm();
                statementForm.Text = dialog.FileName;
                statementForm.MdiParent = _mainForm;
                statementForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                statementForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                statementForm.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: My best guess: `_mainForm` is `null`.

Comment: the thing is, if i remove the " statementForm.MdiParent = _mainForm;" part it pumps out "childforms"(i know they aren't childforms in that context) every time i open a txt file. I tought that meant that _mainform isn't null. That and the fact i don't get a warning about it being null

Comment: How do you initiate `_mainForm` variable?

Comment: private MainForm _mainForm = new MainForm() { IsMdiContainer = true };

Comment: Seems, you're creating new instance of `MainForm`, instead of using existing one. Try: `statementForm.MdiParent = this //referes to a form which calls this method`

Comment: I am trying to use an MVP model and this all happens in the presenter, hence if i do statementForm.MdiParent = this, it'll reference to the presenter class, not to the form. Also i declared _mainform at class scope.

Comment: Yes, you have a Type corresponding to the MDI Form in the Presenter. But you're supposed to use the current instance of that Form and assign it to the Field, not create a new instance of it. If you use `new`, you create a new instance of it, completely unrelated, that you never show. That's why, when you assign this instance to another Form's `MdiParent` property, this *child* Form disappears.

Comment: thanks a lot guys. now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the MainForm in program class as below:

```
static class Program
{
    internal static MainForm _mainForm;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        _mainForm = new MainForm();
        Application.Run(_mainForm);
    }
}
```

Then you can assign it as parent form:

```
statementForm.MdiParent = Program._mainForm;
```